# TestNG inherit @Parameters from parent class

Tags: java, parameters, testng, parallel-testing

I'm trying to get to work a stub for concurrent cross browser test framework using TestNG. BUT seems I cannot get @Parameters from parent class and keep getting

```
Parameter 'browsername' is required by @Configuration on method setup but has not been marked @Optional or defined
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:155)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:358)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createConfigurationParameters(Parameters.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:199)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:348)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:343)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:305)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:254)
```

TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="1265_Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="2" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="92" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.BaseTest"/>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.ChildTest"/>
            <parameter name="browsername" value="chrome"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="93" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.BaseTest"/>
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.ChildTest"/>
            <parameter name="browsername" value="firefox"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

BaseTest

```
public class BaseTest extends Assert {

    protected String browser;

    @BeforeClass
    @Parameters({"browsername"})
    public void setup(String browsername) {
        System.err.println("Browser name in @BeforeClass is " + browsername);
        this.browser = browsername;
    }
}
```

ChildTest

```
public class ChildTest extends BaseTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(browser);
    }
}
```

I didn't find enough information on how to get this to work so if you have any ideas I would like to hear them.

Already checked but not enough info:
[TestNG Annotations in a Superclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558054/testng-annotations-in-a-superclass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try again with `<parameter>` nodes on the `<test>` nodes (and `BaseTest` should be useless):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="1265_Suite" parallel="tests" verbose="2" thread-count="2" preserve-order="true">
    <test name="92" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browsername" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <!--class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.BaseTest"/-->
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.ChildTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="93" parallel="false" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browsername" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <!--class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.BaseTest"/-->
            <class name="com.javacodegeeks.testng.maven.ChildTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: The main idea is to use inheritance (BaseTest) for all test suites. If I will remove the BaseTest from here it will be non sense.

Comment: All test classes will extend BaseTest, right? So, TestNG will detect it by introspection. That's why having it or not into the suite file will have no effect.

Comment: BTW, is my solution fixing your parameter problem?

Comment: Yes, seems your solution is working but there might be another problem on my side which causes this error.